# How to get this type of JSON data in Python

Tags: mysql, json, python-3.x

This is the JSON I got from Mysql query - First Json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 121,
        "name": "A"
    },
    {
        "id": 122,
        "name": "B"
    },
    {
        "id": 123,
        "name": "C"
    },
    {
        "id": 124,
        "name": "D"
    }
]
```

Second Json : But I need in this format

```
{
"user_data":
    [
        {
            "id": 121,
            "name": "A"
        },
        {
            "id": 122,
            "name": "B"
        },
        {
            "id": 123,
            "name": "C"
        },
        {
            "id": 124,
            "name": "D"
        }
    ]
}
```

So that I can identify this is user_data. 
We can differentiate between two json.

The code used to generate the first json is below

```
import pymysql

import json

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='test', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM user")

rows = []
for row in cursor:
    rows += [row]

print(json.dumps(rows, sort_keys=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add this in dictionary object with key `user_data`.

```
 user_data = json.dumps(rows, sort_keys=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
 data = {
    'user_data' : user_data
 }
```

Comment: am newbie to python.. i get this error
C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\PY>te.py
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\PY\te.py", line 15
    data = {
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: there's extra space in the code above you need to delete

Comment: yeah.. i got it thanks.. but the output is not valid json...
{
'user_data':
    [\n
        {\n
            "id": 121,\n
            "name": "A"\n
        },
        {
            "id": 122,\n
            "name": "B"\n
        },
        {
            "id": 123,\n
            "name": "C"\n
        },
        {
            "id": 124,\n
            "name": "D"\n
        }
    \n]
}